# How to get a list of channels in Microsoft Teams using MS Graph?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, access-token

I'm getting the user's token and submitting a request to `/me/joinedTeams` and get the teams IDs of the user.

For each team id, I want to get a list of available channels by sending a request to `/teams/{id}/channels`, however i am getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Failed to execute Skype backend request GetThreadS2SRequest.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-03-12T07:08:38",
      "request-id": "2f1b9408-e7db-4245-be6f-0ec6d67ff160",
      "client-request-id": "2f1b9408-e7db-4245-be6f-0ec6d67ff160"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I fix this?

After which I want to send a request to `/teams/{id}/channels` and get `drive-id`.
And at the end, for each drive-id, get a list of files - `/drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='')`.

Comment: What permissions have you granted?

Comment: By the way, the api does not support private accounts.

Comment: I used an [example](https://github.com/OfficeDev/msteams-tabs-sso-sample-nodejs). When getting permission from user I created a scope like this - https://i.imgur.com/olIdVYA.png @CarlZhao

Comment: Is your account a work account?

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to parse your access token and provide screenshots.

Comment: This is my test result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TytNI.png

Comment: access token - https://i.imgur.com/49eI7YL.png . This is not a work account. @CarlZhao

Comment: The api currently does not support personal accounts:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2dzv.png

Comment: Ok!  I'll move the comment to answer so this post can be treated as archived. If it's helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, this [api call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) does **not support** personal accounts, you must use a work account.

[image]

This is my test result:

[image]